# Azure Application Insights: How to format dates (and numbers)

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm in need of formatting an aggregated date in such a way that it produces an readable **and** sortable format. I am creating a time series that aggregates the number of requests over a period of days using the following code:

```
let us_date = (t:datetime)
{ 
  strcat(    getmonth(t - 8h), "-",  dayofmonth(t - 8h))
};
requests
| project timestamp, client_IP, local_date = us_date(timestamp) 
| where timestamp >= now() -  30d  and timestamp <= now() + 1d
| summarize  uniqueUsers = dcount(client_IP) by usdate = us_date(timestamp)
| order by usdate desc
```

which produces:

[image]

The data is fine, but due to the formatting the sort order is off.

For this to sort correctly should look like `05-09`, but I can't see a way to do this sort of formatting.

Note that I can do the following and get the data in the right **order** but **ugly** format:

```
let us_date = (t:datetime)
{ 
  strcat(   getyear(t - 8h) , '-', getmonth(t - 8h), "-",  dayofmonth(t - 8h))
};
requests
| project timestamp, client_IP 
| where timestamp >= now() -  30d  and timestamp <= now() + 1d
| summarize  uniqueUsers = dcount(client_IP) by usdate = bin(timestamp - 8h,1d)
| order by usdate desc
```

but this produces very verbose list view and also embeds the time into the chart.

[image]

Any ideas how to address either the number formatting issue or how to get another value into the query to allow sorting without throwing off the results?

Answer (score 1):

a) You can `project` after `summarize` to change the column format, column name or column order.

b) You can format the result of `bin`.

Comment: You mean `project` right? Yeah that sort of worked, but still can't get a formatted list that looks right. What I really want is something like a C# string format `yyyy-MM-dd` or `n2` for numbers. Seems odd that something along those lines (or at least `PADL`/`PADR`functions are missing).

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have an insights env to play with, but this is what I used to do back in the day. If you share your updated query maybe we can go from there.

Answer (score 0):

A bit ugly, but string parsing can do the trick here:

```
requests
| project timestamp, client_IP 
| where timestamp >= now() -  30d  and timestamp <= now() + 1d
| summarize  uniqueUsers = dcount(client_IP) by usdate = bin(timestamp - 8h,1d)
| parse tostring(usdate) with year "-" shortDate "T" *
| project shortDate, uniqueUsers** 
| order by shortDate desc
```

The solution lies in the `parse` line - taking only the month and day parts of the date