# Azure application insight rest api- filter on nested datetime item type

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have a nested field which is of type datetime. how can i use datetime comparison like 'ge' 'le' for the nested field in the application insight rest api

For example:

`customDimensions/IngressTimestamp le '2019-04-12T04:05:39.000'`.

I want to get all the records where `IngressTimestamp` is less than `2019-04-12T04:05:39.000`.

Filter used: `customDimensions/IngressTimestamp le '2019-04-12T04:05:39.000'`

I am getting this error:

> TTP/1.1 500 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>
> {   "error": {
>       "message": "Unexpected error occurred",
>       "code": "InternalServerFault",
>       "innererror": {
>         "code": "ServiceError",
>         "message": "Internal Server Error"
>       }   } }

Comment: Have you looked at this ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960136/azure-application-insights-how-to-format-dates-and-numbers

Comment: @MonikaReddy-MSFT, not the same thing, the op asks how to use "le" in $filter when using rest api.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is that you are comparing 2 strings(like compare strings using `ge,gt,lt`), which is not allowed except for the `eq,ne` operator.

You can only use `lt,gt,ge,le` for datetime / numbers, not strings.

I suggest you can use [get query api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query), it's more easier.

write a simple query like below(You can use >,<,<= etc.):

```
customEvents
| where todatetime(customDimensions.mytime) > todatetime("2019-04-12T04:05:39.0000000Z")
```

then put the query in the get query api -> query field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Is there any way where we can cast the data to datetime in the Get/Events api? as it is much easier to consume the returned json which is in key:value pair. The query api returns json with "tables" and "rows"

Comment: @nareshp, not find a way for the casting. Do you consider change the type to datetime in the source code(which you send the telemetry data)?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Looks to me anything inside the "custom dimension" is treated as "string" regardless of datatype.saw this in the api documetation. "customDimensions values are always strings"(https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Events)

Comment: I will take a look at this. And some times before, I wrote a method which can convert the returned results(table) to a dictionary, if you're interesting, I can provide it to you.